# AngularJS "Blob" not working in IE8, IE9 and Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, blob

Please someone help me with my issue using "Blob" in angularJs for downloading excel file. It is working in Chrome and IE10 and 11 but when I used Firefox and IE8&9 there's no popup download that will tell where to save or open it just like in Chrome.

My API data successfully returns the bytes to download but my client-side script cannot download it.

Here is my code in AngularJS:

```
    $scope.LoadData = function () {
        $scope.yearIsLoading = true;
        reportsService.getAssessmentReports($scope.filter).$promise.then(function (response) {
            if (response != null) {
                var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
                saveAs(file, 'Assessments Report');
                $scope.yearIsLoading = false;
            }
        });
    };
```

and here is what I got in IE8 and IE9 error:

```
[IE8 and IE9 Error][1]
```

and in Firefox I can't see the error but nothings happen after I clicked the export button.

Thanks in advance to someone that can help me with this issue. :)

Comment: sorry but I think the link for image is broken but here is the link for the error in IE8 and IE9. Thanks :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi2vt.png

Comment: Please check is it compatible in IE 8: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: As kat pointed out, `Blob` is not supported in your target browsers.

Comment: oh I see. but is there any suggestion on how I can download my byte data in angularJs using the said browser? thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });

if(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/ ") > 0 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge/") > 0)
{
   window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file);
}
```

Comment: Hi @eminlala thanks for the help but still got an error. right now I tried to do what I found in google where I add fake Blob.js in my projects and it already know now the "blob" using IE8 but still can't download the file. I got an error 

"Object doesn't support property or method 'msSaveOrOpenBlob"

Comment: It worked for my download pdf functionality. Sorry about that :(.